# how to fire a function after hovering for a specific time?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make jquery change background color of an item after hovering for 5 seconds . so if cursor has hovered for 3 seconds that wouldn't count ..

```
  $(".test").hover(function(){
    $(".item").css("background","red")
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a timeout on mouse over, and if there is a mouse out event, cancel the timeout.

```js
let timeout;

$(".test").mouseover(function() {
  timeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
    $(".item").css("background", "red")
  }, 5000);
});

$(".test").mouseout(function() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
}

.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">hover me</div>
<div class="item">will change color after 5 sec</div>
```